# Parallax Sliding long movieclip Animate CC and TweenJs

Tags: jquery-animate, animate-cc, tweenjs

I'm creating a sliding movieclip in Animate CC. I have a movie clip that is 19200 pixels wide. How can I TweenJS the movieclip 1920 to the left when the right arrow is clicked and TweenJS the same movieclip 1920 to the right when the left arrow is clicked?

Here is what I have so far in Animate CC HTML5 Canvas:

```
/* Mouse Click Event
Clicking on the specified symbol instance executes a function in which you can add your own custom code.
*/

this.next.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
    createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip_1).to({x:-1920}, 500, Ease.getPowIn(2.2))
}

this.prev.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
    createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip_1).to({x:1920}, 500, Ease.getPowIn(2.2))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) In your code, you have two functions named equally, but with different code inside. The same name is specified on the listener-adding code. Because of that, both listeners will be linked to just one of the functions (specifically, the second one, for being the last one declared).

```
this.next.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
    /* Code */
}

this.prev.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler()
{
    /* Code */
}
```

To solve that, changing the names of both functions will be enough. Of course, you'll have to change the names in the listener-adding code.

### nextMouseClickHandler()

```
this.next.addEventListener("click", nextMouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function nextMouseClickHandler() {
    /* Code */
}
```

### prevMouseClickHandler()

```
this.prev.addEventListener("click", prevMouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function prevMouseClickHandler() {
    /* Code */ 
}
```

2) On the `to` method of the Tweens in both functions, in the `ease` parameter, before specifying the ease, you need to add `createjs`:

### Tween in nextMouseClickHandler()

```
createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip_1).to({x:-1920}, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowIn(2.2));
```

### Tween in prevMouseClickHandler()

```
createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip_1).to({x:1920}, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowIn(2.2));
```

Solving both issues will result in the following code:

```
this.next.addEventListener("click", nextMouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function nextMouseClickHandler() {
    createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip_1).to({x:-1920}, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowIn(2.2));
}

this.prev.addEventListener("click", prevMouseClickHandler.bind(this));

function prevMouseClickHandler() {
    createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip_1).to({x:1920}, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowIn(2.2));
}
```

This code works in Animate CC, replicating the MovieClip names you specified.